# throwing exceptions from EJB interceptors

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

Let's say I have an interceptor that looks smth like this:

```
public class AuthorizationInterceptor {

  Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

  @AroundInvoke
  private Object authorize(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception{
    // ... some other logic for authorization

    if (!allowedMethods.contains(ic.getMethod().getName())){
      log.info("Authorization failed. Preparing to throw exception");
      throw new AuthException("Authorization failed for method " +
                ic.getMethod().getName());
    }

    return ic.proceed();
  }
}
```

which is applied to different methods from my EJBs.

I would normally expect the exception throed to be passed to the invoking client, like all normal EJB exceptions.

Apparently this doesn't happen if I throw it from an Interceptor... It's not even logged on the server; like it's never thrown although it is - the return statement is never executed.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using GF 3.0.1

Comment: Tried setting breakpoints at `if (!allowed...)` to see what really happens under the hood?

Comment: I can't get the debugger to work with NB + GF; I only use logging for debug.

Comment: It looks like I have some logic messed up `client side`; I've setup a SSCCE and it works fine;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to try:

```
1. Check that the authorize(...) method is called.
2. Try making the authorize(...) method public instead of private.
3. Check that the EJB has an annotation like this:
      @Interceptors(AuthorizationInterceptor.class)
```

Comment: 1. the method is indeed called - i can see the log message executing; Number 2 & 3 are also checked. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

After searching a bit for this issue, I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284031/what-is-the-proper-way-to-deal-with-exceptions-in-interceptors-in-ejb3) which was answered a few minutes ago. Quote:

> I don't think there is a correct way
>   to do that. Methods should throw only
>   the exceptions they declared, and an
>   interceptor shouldn't add a new one.
>   My personal case got fixed by adding
>   an error code to our default exception
>   which is thrown by all methods.

Question author is the same person who answered and accepted this answer, so I guess he was trying to solve the same issue as you and came to conclusion that it cannot be done.

Comment: darioo, thanks for taking the time to research this. I'm not experiencing the same issues as this user; after I corrected my problem client-side, the interceptor throws exactly the defined exception, so everything is fine, for now :)